# Why doesn't Eclipse show default proposals for JSTL code?

Tags: eclipse, jstl

I have the following problem:
I am working on a .jsp file on eclipse. My problem is that Eclipse somehow doesn't support default proposals for jstl code `<c:[anything]` and gives out the warning `Unknown tag(<c:[anything]>)`. What's strange about it is that syntax highlighting works perfectly fine for JSTL code and for different code (Java, PHP, HTML...) there are default proposals. My servlet container is Tomcat and I've already copied the file jstl.jar in `[folder]/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/` but didn't help.

When I take a look at Eclipse->Window->Preferences->Web->JSP Files->Editor->Content Assist the checkboxes *JSP Proposals*, *JSP Java Proposals* and *JSP Template Proposals* are checked.

I feel like it's actually pretty obvious to figure out where the problem is but I just don't get it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. I still don't konw what it actually was but I just reinstalled tomcat (I'm working on a lubuntu system) and this time I didn't do it manually by extracting a .tar.bz2 file but via apt-get install ... . Then I created a new eclipse project and told it to use tomcat as servlet container. Then it worked right away so I assume that there was just something wrong with the way I installed tomcat before (maybe some variable didn't point to the correct directory or so).

Answer (score 0):

There are some event that it would trigger eclipse to validate files. You can rebuild eclipse project. or open problems viewer, and delete the problem which you can make sure the problem is not problem, if you really import the jstl.jar, next time it wouldn't warn you.

Comment: Tried to rebuild the project by creating a new workspace, adding a new project and a test.jsp file, but didn't help. If I open the problem view (assume you mean Window->Show view->Other->General->Problem) Eclipse doesn't show me any problems. The weird thing is that eclipse tells me "I don't know what you're just coding but nevermind, I still do proper syntax highlighting".